# Looking for Show/Movie from childhood

Tags: story-identification, movie

I once saw a movie where I remember the protagonists entering paintings and interacting with the characters in them, specifically Botticelli's "La Primavera," interacting with the women in the orchard, and also the "Lion of St. Mark" painting, being flown on the back of the lion through Venice? I can't remember much other than that, they likely went into other paintings, but those are the two I can remember. In terms of timeline, I would say around the early 2000s, I think it was animated, and I would guess its a movie, but it could have been a show.
If anyone could find what this was, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Maybe [Search for the Jewel of Polaris: Mysterious Museum](https://www.radiotimes.com/movie-guide/b-7dsk6t/search-for-the-jewel-of-polaris-mysterious-museum/) (1999)? I'm having trouble finding out if those two specific paintings were in it, though.

Comment: Roughly when did you see this movie? Was it new at the time? In cinema, on disc or tape or on tv?

Comment: I recall an episode of the cartoon show "Darkwing Duck" with a villainess who could travel through various paintings, and adopted the style of each painting that she entered.